# How is Ethereum Plasma different from Ardor's Parent Child chain feature?

Tags: tokens, plasma

From my understanding Ethereum's plasma is similar to Ardor's parent child chain feature, but what are the main differences from these two technologies?

Ardor is fully proof of stake and it lets you mine/stake its child coins within the system, does plasma have this feature of mining/staking its child tokens?